# Declaring struct instances as static/local in main() with while(1)

Tags: c, user-interface, arm, embedded, cortex-a

I am working on microntroller RZA1, with KPIT GNUARM 16 toolchain, in e2 studio. I am not an expert on the subject, so I'll try to explain the problem the best that I can. The issue is related to a structure `mainwindow`, defined in my code, which contains important features of the graphical interface:

```
typedef struct
{
    page_t      pages[MAXNUMPAGE];
    logger_t    storico;
    messagges_t messaggio;
    graph_t     grafico;
} mainwindow_t;
```

In the `main()` function I declare a `local` instance of this struct, as it contains a `while(1)` loop, which is used to refresh the GUI application in case of user interaction (i.e pushbutton clicked). The problem that I have encountered is that there's a difference in the way program executes in case the instance of `mainwindow_t` is declared with or without `static` keyword. For instance,

```
main()
{
    static mainwindow_t mainwindow;
    ....
    init_pages(mainwindow.pages);
    while(1)
    {
        page_update(mainwindow.pages);
    }
}
```

works perfectly well, whereas with only `mainwindow_t mainwindow;` it seems that the changes made in the function init_pages() had no effect: entire content of the array page[MAXNUMPAGE] is uninitialized.

Therefore, my question is: should there be any functional difference between non-static local and static local declaration of an array inside a function, if that function basically never returns ?

Comment: "if I were to share the code, I would have to share several .c files, and I have never seen anyone here doing such a thing. – danmar"  there is no reason why you cant make a complete minimal example as outlined by stackoverflow, no reason why you have to show your whole project, if the question truly has to do with static vs not then you can demonstrate that the other function doesnt matter.

Comment: @old_timer I agree, but this is a very specific case, in which it seems that the issue is related to stack usage. I did try to reproduce the problem with a minimal example, but it seems that the issue disappears without the rest of the code, and it works both with and without the instance being declared static.

Comment: Try declaring the variable as non-static with an initializer like this:  `mainwindow_t mainwindow = { 0 };` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: if the problem is in your declaration within the function then this is not a specific case and the answer will be seen in the compiler output.  If this is related to the rest of the code then you have a bug in your code or a bug in the compiler, stack frames have nothing to do with this unless there is a compiler bug.

Comment: of course the local vs static is going to show a different stack usage, one the struct is in .bss and where allowed only pointers to it are needed in the function the other the struct itself is needed, and depending on what else you are doing in that function can easily multiply the stack consumption. (for example in the ... you have other statics vs non that you are not showing us)

Comment: But if you have decided that you have found the issue then you can delete this question.

Comment: @dbush It seems that your suggestion did the trick. May I ask you how this way of initializing the struct affects the problem ?

Comment: @danmar See my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with whether the variable lives on the stack or not.  It has to do with initialization.

Variables with **static storage duration**, i.e. file-scope variables or local variables with the `static` keyword, are implicitly initialized so that (loosely speaking) all variables with arithmetic type are initialized to 0 and all pointer variables are initialized to `NULL`.

In contrast, variables with **automatic storage duration**, i.e. variables declared inside of a function, are *not* initialized if there is no explicit initializer and its value is **indeterminate**.

While you didn't show your initialization function, it apparently doesn't set all fields in `mainwindow.pages` and depends on the other fields being zero-initialized.  When `mainwindow` is declared non-static, this results in your program reading some indeterminate fields which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which explains why the problem mysteriously disappears when you attempt to trim down the code.

Adding an initializer to `mainwindow` addresses this issue by setting any fields explicitly listed, while applying the static object initialization rules to any remaining fields not explicitly initialized.

Comment: On point, because I have verified the data of each element in the array `page[MAXNUMPAGES]` and the last element of the array did have random values, when the` struct` was declared as non-`static` local instance. Thank you for your help.